# How to fix a bug in the application. Stack trace from Google play console

Tags: android, apk

```
Exception java.lang.NullPointerException:
at com.package.q.activities.MainActivity$a.b (SourceFile:3)
at z4.a.o (SourceFile:3)
at z4.a$b.handleMessage (SourceFile:8)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8653)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

I can't figure out what is the reason. Android Studio compiles without errors.

Comment: It seems that it’s obfuscated as proguard is enabled you will need to check your mapping file to know more details .. also you can try debugging while proguard is enabled in your current code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You should add more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can run apps in the Android Studio emulator or in your mobile directly from Android Studio. Clicking the run button in the top right corner or pressing Shift+F10 will run the app in the emulator by default. To run the app in a physical Android device, you need to do the following:

1. Go to Settings in your device.
2. Search for Build Number and tap it seven times to get developer access
3. Turn on USB debugging.
4. Then, connect your device to your PC using a USB cable.
5. Android Studio will automatically detect the connected device.
6. Choose the device in the device list and hit run.
7. The app will run in your physical Android device.

Comment: is it possible to run a stack trace in studio? or how else is it possible to see my mistakes in the studio before publishing in google play

Comment: By mistakes do you mean errors in your code?

Comment: I am newbie. I would like to get rid of the error that I posted above. how is it possible to do this?

Comment: According  to error, some variable in your code has a null value. Without your code I can’t help you much. So, pls add the code where you get the error in your question.

Comment: thanks for the answer. the problem is that this is an application and I myself do not know in which code this error occurs. if in the studio it was possible to view the errors that Google Play displays, then I would quickly find the cause of the error. I will look for a variable with a zero value. as a result, I will write the result and how it turned out to fix it. Thank you!